# Question about AVAudioSession channel UID

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I'm using `AVAudioSession` to see which route I'm on at the moment.
Now, looking at the output response I see something like this:

```
 <AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x28263c1c0, type = BluetoothA2DPOutput; name = FreeBuds Lite; UID = E4:34:93:3C:4B:5F-tacl; selectedDataSource = (null)>
```

According to Apple's documentation the UID is `A system-assigned unique identifier (UID) for the port.` I wanted to know if it means that for each different device the number will be different (so far its seems it is) and also that for the same device the number will be presistent an won't change over time?

Comment: the documentation is guaranteeing you no such thing, but in practice you might be lucky. I think you need to do some experiments and be prepared for what you discover to change over time.